# Как почистить память после удаления структуры из List - golang

Tags: массивы, golang, память

Как я могу удалить из памяти структуру и чтобы она вообще не вызывалась? Мне нужно чтобы когда я убирал из List она чистилась так же из памяти и останавливался цикл, но он не останавливается. Подскажите как сделать правильно, спасибо заранее.

```
type Player struct {
    PlayerID int
}

func (p Player) Create() *Player {
    fmt.Println("Create Player:", p.PlayerID)

    go func() {
        for {
            println("test")
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
        }
    }()

    return &p
}

func main() {

    playersList := list.New()
    playersList.PushFront(Player{PlayerID: 1}.Create())

    for e := playersList.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
        println("Remove Player:", e.Value.(*Player).PlayerID)
        playersList.Remove(e)
        e.Value = nil
        runtime.GC()
    }

    fmt.Scanf("h")
}
```

[log]
Create Player: 1
Remove Player: 1
test
test.
test...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Go нет ни деструкторов, ни финализаторов. Зато есть сборщик мусора, который собирает висящие объекты. Горутина объектом не является, поэтому её сборщик мусора не остановит. Вам нужно останавливать горутину явным образом.

Идиоматический способ завершения горутин - передача сообщения через канал.

```go
package main

import (
    "container/list"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Player struct {
    PlayerID int
    done     chan bool
}

func NewPlayer(PlayerID int) *Player {
    return &Player{
        PlayerID: PlayerID,
        // Нулевой буфер, так как канал не используется для передачи сообщений
        // Сигналом для завершения будет закрытие канала
        done: make(chan bool, 0),
    }
}
func (p *Player) Start() *Player {
    fmt.Println("Create Player:", p.PlayerID)

    go func() {
    LOOP:
        for {
            fmt.Println("test: player ID: ", p.PlayerID)
            select {
            case <-p.done:
                // ветка `case <-channel` срабатывает в двух случаях: в канале есть данные и канал был закрыт
                break LOOP
            case <-time.After(time.Second * 2):
                continue
            }
        }
        fmt.Println("done: player ID: ", p.PlayerID)
    }()

    return p
}
func (p *Player) Stop() *Player {
    fmt.Println("Stop Player:", p.PlayerID)
    // сигнал для завершения - закрытие канала
    close(p.done)
    return p
}

func main() {
    playersList := list.New()
    playersList.PushFront(NewPlayer(1).Start())
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

    for e := playersList.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
        p := e.Value.(*Player)
        println("Remove Player:", p.PlayerID)
        p.Stop()

        playersList.Remove(e)
        e.Value = nil
    }

    fmt.Scanf("h")
}
```